# Issues downloading Pomoxis

Tags: python, windows, conda

When I try to download Pomoxis on a windows computer with

```
conda install pomoxis
```

These are the errors I get.

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: |
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - pomoxis -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|3.7.10|3.7.10|3.6.12|3.7.9|3.6.12|3.6.9|3.6.9|3.6.9|3.6.9|3.4.*',build='1_73_pypy|2_73_pypy|3_73_pypy|1_73_pypy|0_73_pypy|5_73_pypy|5_73_pypy|4_73_pypy|0_73_pypy']

Your python: python=3.9

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.
```

Even when I change the version of python to 3.5 or 3.6 I get the same error (except it says python=3.5 or 3.6). Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: How are you changing your Python version? If the error still says `Your python: python=3.9`, then you're not changing the Python version that the `conda` command is using. You should verify that you're modifying and using the correct environment.

Comment: I tried changing to `python=3.6` and this is what I got: 
`Specifications:

  - pomoxis -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|3.7.10|3.7.10|3.6.12|3.7.9|3.6.12|3.6.9|3.6.9|3.6.9|3.6.9|3.4.*',build='1_73_pypy|3_73_pypy|4_73_pypy|5_73_pypy|1_73_pypy|0_73_pypy|5_73_pypy|2_73_pypy|0_73_pypy']

Your python: python=3.6
`

Comment: Please edit questions to add info, especially when including long outputs from shell.

Answer (score 0):

Conda's conflict reporting is unreliable. Instead, using Mamba, I conclude that the main issue is that [Bioconda simply does not support Windows](https://bioconda.github.io/user/versions.html#operating-systems), and the particular failure is that there is no Conda build of `bcftools` for **win-64** platform, which is a requirement for `pomoxis`.

**Mamba Output**

```bash
$ CONDA_SUBDIR=win-64 mamba create -n foo pomoxis

                  __    __    __    __
                 /  \  /  \  /  \  /  \
                /    \/    \/    \/    \
███████████████/  /██/  /██/  /██/  /████████████████████████
              /  / \   / \   / \   / \  \____
             /  /   \_/   \_/   \_/   \    o \__,
            / _/                       \_____/  `
            |/
        ███╗   ███╗ █████╗ ███╗   ███╗██████╗  █████╗
        ████╗ ████║██╔══██╗████╗ ████║██╔══██╗██╔══██╗
        ██╔████╔██║███████║██╔████╔██║██████╔╝███████║
        ██║╚██╔╝██║██╔══██║██║╚██╔╝██║██╔══██╗██╔══██║
        ██║ ╚═╝ ██║██║  ██║██║ ╚═╝ ██║██████╔╝██║  ██║
        ╚═╝     ╚═╝╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═╝     ╚═╝╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝

        mamba (0.13.0) supported by @QuantStack

        GitHub:  https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba
        Twitter: https://twitter.com/QuantStack

█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████


Looking for: ['pomoxis']

bioconda/win-64          [====================] (00m:00s) Done
pkgs/r/noarch            [====================] (00m:00s) No change
pkgs/main/noarch         [====================] (00m:00s) Done
pkgs/r/win-64            [====================] (00m:00s) Done
bioconda/noarch          [====================] (00m:00s) Done
pkgs/main/win-64         [====================] (00m:00s) Done
conda-forge/noarch       [====================] (00m:01s) Done
conda-forge/win-64       [====================] (00m:02s) Done
Encountered problems while solving:
  - nothing provides bcftools needed by pomoxis-0.2.2-py_0
```

Alternatives for using Bioconda on Windows are through WSL or a containerization system (e.g., Docker).

Comment: what happens when it says that bcftools is needed.... I am at that point and do not know exactly what to do. Is there some way to install it on windows?

Comment: @Schuyler2000 there is no way to install it directly on Windows via Conda. Instead, run Linux on your Windows machine and install Conda (I’d recommend Mambaforge) inside the Linux instance.